# Matrix notation as vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, notation

I am a beginner in linear algebra, and I do not know how to interpret the following matrix notation:
$$A = [w_1, w_2, ..., w_m, u_1, u_2, ..., u_n]$$
where $w_1, w_2, ..., w_m, u_1, u_2, ..., u_n$ are vectors.

Does this mean that each of the vectors is a column of the matrix? Or a row?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The vectors are the columns of $A$.